# Infinite loop when pushing into array using UseState()?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

I would like to store the data of a response into an array for reuse. I am using Axios for this. The issue I receive is that when I push into the array, it loops getBoroughAndId() and keeps pushing into the array. I can tell because I get a console.log() response where it keeps telling me I am making too many requests. Any advice? Thanks.

Edit: After taking another gander, I think the issue is that the id is always changing when running getBoroughAndId. I'm not sure how to stop this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { airtableApi } from '../services/api/airtable';
import { BoroughDay, BoroughGroup } from '../types/api';

const IndexPage = () => {
  const [boroughs, setBoroughs] = useState<BoroughDay[]>([]);
  const [boroughGroups, setBoroughGroups] = useState<BoroughGroup[]>([]);

  const getBoroughsAndDays = () => {
    airtableApi
      .getBoroughsAndDays()
      .then((response) => {
        setBoroughs(response);
      })
      .catch(() => { });
  };

  const getBoroughAndId = (id: string) => {
    airtableApi
      .getBoroughAndId(id)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setBoroughGroups(arr => [...arr, response])
        return response;
      })
      .catch(() => { });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getBoroughsAndDays()
  }, [boroughGroups])

  return (
    <>
      {boroughs.map((data) => {
        getBoroughAndId(data.id);
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

Here is my corrected code. It works a lot better now, with less nonsense and everything being done in the first function.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { airtableApi } from '../services/api/airtable';
import { BoroughDay, BoroughGroup } from '../types/api';

const IndexPage = () => {

  const [boroughs, setBoroughs] = useState<BoroughDay[]>([]);
  const [boroughGroups, setBoroughGroups] = useState<BoroughGroup[]>([]);

  const getBoroughsDays = () => {
    airtableApi
      .getBoroughsAndDays()
      .then((response) => {
        setBoroughs(response.records);
        response.records.map((data) => {
          setBoroughGroups(arr => [...arr, {id: data.id, "Borough": data.fields["Borough"]}])
        })
      })
      .catch(() => { })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getBoroughsDays();
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {boroughGroups.map(data => <div>{data.id} {data.Borough}</div>)}
    </>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to call `getBoroughAndId` for every element in `boroughs` on every render? You might want to put that in an effect as well, and just use your `boroughs` and `boroughGroups` state for rendering.

Comment: You update boroughGroups each time boroughs are updated and then update boroughs because boroughGroups  are updated, there is no way out of this flow. What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Thank you for your feedback. The desired flow is to have boroughs be called in order to retrieve the array returned by the records by Airtable. It only updates when Airtable updates. Then boroughGroups stores information from each element of borough (only the id and the name of the group) and pushes that information into its own array.

Comment: How will you know that Airtable updates?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova The function airtableApi.getBoroughsAndDays() applies a get function from Airtable API. I guess I just assumed that whenever something is added, edited, or deleted from Airtable, the program will pick it up. So I guess on every refresh or render of the page.

Comment: Well, you can't call getBoroughsAndDays each time the components re-renders, because it itself will trigger another re-render. If you don't need to update boroughs after initial load useEffect(() => {getBoroughsAndDays()}, []) will do, overwise you need to come up with a way to check if the data has been updated or not

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Thanks for your patience in helping me. It is making more sense now, I just need more practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to tell you the mistake you are committing, I will tell you the whole flow of your program.

1. First of all when component mounts, useEffect will be called, which will call the getBoroughsAndDays function.

Note: boroughGroups in dependency array in useEffect is causing an infinite loop

2. This function (getBoroughsAndDays()) will update the value of boroughs(using setBoroughs)
3. Now since the state updated the function will re render, hence output will be shown on the screen
4. Now observe, here you are calling "getBoroughAndId(data.id)" function (inside map function), which is updating the value of boroughGroups(using setBoroughGroups)
5. Now since the value of boroughGroups have changed, the useEffect method will be called, which will again trigger the "getBoroughsandDays()" function, repeating the whole process again, so that is the reason, it is creating infinite loop.

Note: When any value inside dependency array changes useEffect will be called.

Solution:
I don't know what functionality you want to achieve but remove "boroughGroups" dependency from useEffect (In this way it will behave like componentDidMount).

Comment: Omg amazing!! This actually solidifies my understanding of useEffect a little more than I knew before. Thank you for this.

Comment: Glad that my answer helped you!
Let me give you a little more insight about useEffect (they are literally one of the best things in react for me)
Useffect can behave like:
1) componentDidMount (when dependency array is empty)
2) componentDidUpdate (when dependency array has some value)
3) componentWillUnmount (when useEffect returns something ) (can be used when to empty some data when component unmounts)

Comment: Whenever you use some values in useEffect, it expects us to include them in dependency array , and when that value changes the useEffect behaves like componentDidUpdate. (This can lead to infinite loop, so use it with caution xD)

Do upvote my answer , if you liked it! 
Good luck

Comment: Upvoted. No problem, thank you for the informaton.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `useEffect` hook that updates state: `boroughs` whenever value of state: `boroughGroups` changes.

In the return statement, you iterate through `boroughs` and update `boroughGroups`.
Back to the first statement.

To stop this infinite loop, stop updating `boroughGroups`, that triggers `useEffect` everytime.

```
useEffect(() => {getBoroughsAndDays()}, []);
```